# Replace void rvalue reference

Tags: c++

I am writing a kind of message passing interface, where a frontend request a variable of type `Var` to a backend. In the most simple form, it reads:

```
Var backend();
Var interface() {return backend();}
Var frontend() {return interface();}
```

Unfortunately, although `interface` implementation is aware of type `Var`, its signature is not. Had a void rvalue reference existed in c++, I would use something like

```
void&& interface();
```

with proper casting, because I want this process to stay copy free as most as possible, and I do not want `Var` constructor to be called. I came up with this hack:

```
void interface(void* p) {new (p) Var(backend());}
Var get()
{
    char hack[sizeof(Var)];
    impl_get(static_cast<void*>(&hack));
    return std::move(*reinterpret_cast<A*>(hack));
}
```

Which, as far as I know, only calls the move constructor of `Var` (if defined). Is this solution standard and safe and is there any cleaner way of doing that?

Comment: You don't need rvalue references everywhere to prevent copying. For example, return values are often moved out of functions if (N)RVO hasn't already covered it.

Comment: Why don't you just include the necessary headers?

Comment: Maybe you can make it template?

Comment: It is a pluggable architecture, I don't necessarily have the headers or type information.

Comment: "Which, as far as I know, only calls the move constructor of..." it does not. It tries to find if the move constructor is defined. If it is not defined, it will fallback to the copy constructor. If the move constructor is explicitly deleted, as in `Var::~Var() = delete;`, then the code will not get compiled. Basically, the behaviour of `std::move` is determined based on the implementation of `Var`.